# How to use span and offset class in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am just a beginner in Twitter Bootstrap.

I am trying to use its grid functionality by using classes span and offset.

Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

ul.unstyled > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
</style> 
 </head>

<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="span3 offset5">
<ul class="unstyled">
<li>
<label for="optionsRadios1">A.</label>
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Option 1
</li>
<li>
<label for="optionsRadios2">B.</label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Option 2 
</li>
<li>
<label for="optionsRadios3">C.</label>
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3">option3</li>
<li><label for="optionsRadios4">D.</label>
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4">option4</li>

<li><label for="optionsRadios5">E.</label>
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios5" value="option5">option5</li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span3 offset5">
<input type="checkbox">Mark To review</input>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am mistaking?
I am not getting offset margin in my webpage.

[image]

I used code described in Bootstrap example http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem
My HTML webpage code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>

<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="span9">
    Level 1 column
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">Level 2</div>
      <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I am not getting my page with no margins or offsets. Here's the screenshot:
[image] I am unable to point where the problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Initial Answer

You will have to wrap your `<div>` elements inside a `<div class="row">` element. this should do the trick. Have a look at the examples at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem to learn more.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span3 offset2">...</div>
</div>
```

Also you do not close your `<input>` elements, which might yield undesired results. Finally I can't find any import of Bootstrap's CSS file. Hence, the styles for the grid systems are not available in your web page.

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VTbAA/1/

### Update (2nd Example)

Again, you are missing your CSS import. It works fine as soon as you add Bootstrap's CSS file. Note that you are also missing to close some `<div>` elements. Furthermore, Bootstrap provides a 12-based grid system. Hence your columns should add up to 12.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">Level 1 column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6 offset3">Level 2</div>
      <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The important line is the import statement:

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response i used a simple example of some div tags which are not showing any effect of offset class please point a little in 2nd example as i described.

Comment: Updated the answer. Note that you still miss to close some `div` tags. This however is not the actual problem. Its the missing CSS. Also, it is a 12-based grid systems, hence the columns shoul add up to 12.

Comment: No problem. I have adjusted the example to fix the other issues as well.

Comment: one second it is giving label in different line and radio option in other line now how to fix that please help a little ??

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve. As this is not really part of the initial question, I suggest to either move to the chat or to setup a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31462/discussion-between-ritesh-mehandiratta-and-fynn)